# Карта гексагональной доски

Tags: алгоритм

Имеем гексагональную доску (см.рисунок) с длиной грани **D**
Имеем три измерения (направления): красное, синее и зеленое
Имеем номера линий по трем направлениям (конкретные значения не критичны, они могут быть любыми)

Необходимо составить карту зависимостей номера линии в измерении, позиции ячейки в этой линии для каждой ячейки всей доски.
То есть для номера **1** нужно получить данные по трем измерениям: `1:(1,0), 2:(7,0), 3:(1,0)`
аналогично к примеру для номера **21**: `1:(3,5), 2:(6,3), 3:(10,3)`
`(3,5)` например означает линия 3, ячейка 5.

Для красного измерения все весьма просто:

```
S = K * D + N + summ(range(1,K-1)) - 2*summ(range(1,K-D))
```

где

- **K** - номер линии
- **D** - размер доски (меньшая грань)
- **N** - номер ячейки в линии
- **range** - функция, возвращающая диапазон, а если левая граница больше правой, то возвращающая 0
- **S** - номер ячейки для всей доски

Никак не могу сообразить, как вычислить два других измерения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас странная координатная сетка. Обычно гексы представляют как 2-мерный массив со смещением каждой нечетной линии на 0,5 в отрисовке и доступом к 6 соседям вместо 8 в логике.

Comment: @KromStern спасибо. Так значительно проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользовался советом @KromStern:

> У вас странная координатная сетка. Обычно гексы представляют как 2-мерный массив со смещением каждой нечетной линии на 0,5 в отрисовке и доступом к 6 соседям вместо 8 в логике.

Все получилось значительно проще и нагляднее:

```
---*-*-*---
--*-*-*-*--
-*-*-*-*-*-
--*-*-*-*--
---*-*-*---
```

Алгоритм прост:

- создаем промежуточный прямоугольный массив по схеме выше
- вычисляем формулы для трех измерений: `dim1`, `dim2`, `dim3`
- заполняем промежуточный массив
- перенумеровываем ключи промежуточного массива, начиная с нуля

Для Python получился следующий код, создающий карту доски:

```
def dim1( k, n, d ):
    y = k
    x = abs( k - d + 1) + 2 * n
    return [ y, x ]

def dim2( k, n, d ):
    t = k-d+1
    y = n
    if t>0: y+= t
    x = abs( 1-d )+2*k-n
    if t>0: x-= t
    return [ y, x ]

def dim3( k, n, d ):
    t1 = k - d + 1
    t2 = d - k - 1
    y = n
    if t2>0: y+=t2
    x = k + n
    if t1>0: x+=t1
    return [ y, x ]

def pushToRes( y, x, d, val, res, dimens ):
    ind = y*4*d+x
    if ( not ind in res.keys() ): res[ind] = {}
    res[ind][ dimens ] = val

res = {}
d= 7
lens = list(range(d,2*d))+list(range(2*d-2,d-1,-1)) # d=3, lens = [3,4,5,4,3]

for i in range( 0, 2*d-1 ):
    for j in range( lens[i] ):
        d1 = dim1( i, j ,d )
        d2 = dim2( i, j ,d )
        d3 = dim3( i, j ,d )
        pushToRes( d1[0], d1[1], d, [i,j], res, 1 )
        pushToRes( d2[0], d2[1], d, [i,j], res, 2 )
        pushToRes( d3[0], d3[1], d, [i,j], res, 3 )

print( res )
print( len( res ) ) // контроль, что число ячеек соответствует действительности
x = list(res.keys())
x.sort()
res2 = [ res[i] for i in x ]
print( res2 )
```